# ¿Se puede utilizar un cut -d y watch - n con el comando iostat?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, script

Quiero sacar una información en especifico de el comando iostat cada 2 segundos con el comando watch -n y ademas utilizando un cut -d para seleccionar la información que me interesa. El siguiente es mi comando

`watch - n 2 iostat | cut -d ":" -f 2`

El problema esta en que una vez ejecuto ese código no me sale ninguna información en pantalla

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con:

```
$ watch -n 2 "iostat | cut -d ':' -f 2"
```

No sé si funcione, pero cuando yo escribo `iostat` en mi equipo, no me aparece ningún campo con el delimitador de los dos puntos *:*